# How do I go about splitting up 1 LP problem into 2?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, constraints

I have to set up a linear programming problem corresponding to the following scenario:

---

[image]

---

From Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I tried:

Let $x_i$ denote allocated amount of budget in advertising media i

for i=1,2,3,4,5 corresponding to TV,radio,newspaper,billboard U, billboard R

Apparently, I'm supposed to **split up into 2 LP Problems**.

**LP Problem 1:**

Maximise sales increase:

$$z = [2.9 \ 2.7 \ 2.5 \ 2.7 \ 2.6] \cdot [x_1 \ x_2 \ x_3 \ x_4 \ x_5]$$

s.t.

$$x_i \ge 0$$

a

1. $$x_1 + x_2 \le (30\%)(1m)$$
2. $$x_4 + x_5 \ge (20\%)(1m)$$

b

$$x_2 \ge 1.5x_1$$

c

$$x_4 \le x_5$$

e

$$\sum_i x_i = 1m$$

d

$$x_3 \le 200,000$$

**LP Problem 2:**

Maximise sales increase:

$$z = [2.9 \ 2.7 \ 2.5 \ 2.7 \ 2.6] \cdot [x_1 \ x_2 \ x_3 \ x_4 \ x_5] + 0.1*(x_3 - 200,000)$$

s.t.

the same constraints except

d

$$\color{red}{x_3 > 200,000}$$

Since rebates are after the fact unlike discounts, the budget (constraint e) is not affected.

If it was instead discount, the objective function is the same, but the budget constraint is

$1m = \sum_i x_i - x_3 + 0.9*(x_3 - 200,000)$

Answer (score 1):

In the problem 2 keep exactly the same objective as the one from problem 1.

- Just add the variables $$y_1 \ge 0$$$y_1$ will be the part of $x3$ above $200, 000$
- Change the constraint d, by :
  $$x_3 = 200,000 + y_1$$
  or in the standard form :
  $$x_3 - y_1 = 200,000$$
- And change the constraint e, by :
  $$x_1 + x_2 + 0.9y_1 + x_4 + x_5 = 1,000,000 - 200,000$$
- Then solve problem 1 and problem 2, the one that gives the better objective is your solution

Comment: You could also use Mixed Integer Programming, and have only one problem

Comment: Thanks MikeDundee! ^-^ Is that really $y_1 \ge 0$ and not $> 0$ ?

Comment: Constraints in linear programming are only of the form : >=, <=, =. You cannot have strict  <, > constraints

Comment: Right thanks. Btw MikeDundee, I think rebate affects objective function rather than constraint because rebates are after the purchase. If it was a discount instead, I think we keep the objective function but change the constraint as you said...I think?

Comment: You are welcome. I do not think that I understand the difference that you make between a rebate and a discount. Concretly what the rebate/discount of this problem will do is that it will allow us to purchase more advertising, since we have a fixed budged. So the fixed budged constraint need to be modified. But the objective is the same, we want to maximize the total impact of the advertising campain on the sales, the sale increase coefficients by advertising unit are the same, the only difference is that the rebate will allow us to purchase more advertising units. Do you see what I am saying ?

Comment: The sale increases are the same, but I don't think the sale increase coefficients are the same. I think your assumption is that we have or can borrow until we are a little more than 200,000 to spare to make use of the rebate which we expect to get immediately? I'm thinking rebates increase revenue while discounts decrease cost. Both profit increasing but in different ways.

Comment: I think that here we don't have a notion of revenue to maximize, only a notion of advertising efficiency. When I read the subject I understand that the cost will be fixed (1 million) no matter what. But maybe I don't understand correctly as english is not my first language

Comment: The objective function is revenue, is it not? PS Not your first language? Doesn't show :P

Comment: MikeDundee, edited my answer. How is it?